# VB2010 Extract a string of numbers from a string or array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, numbers, extract

I have a filepath that I would like to pull the starting directory job number from the beginning of the filepath.  Except I don't know how to just pull the number string out of the filepath string. (i.e.: filepath= Q:\2456_blah_blah\file.txt - or something) I'd like to just pull '2456' as a string,
then put that number string into TextBox2 I've created on my form.
The code I have so far spits out a '0' instead of the number string desired.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName = Nothing

    If Me.OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.OpenFileDialog1.FileName

    End If

    If GetInfo() = True Then

        For Each Xitem In ExcelRowList

            Dim lvitem As ListViewItem
            lvitem = Me.ListView1.Items.Add(Xitem.C1)

        Next

    End If
'''Here is where I call the GetFilePathOnly function
    TextBox2.Text = GetFilePathOnly(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
'''Section below is what defines my number string, then I call it above for the Button1.Click operation(towards the end)
Private Function GetFilePathOnly(ByVal Fullpath As String) As String
    Dim File As String = Fullpath
    Dim number As Double = Val(File)
    Dim outcome As String = number.ToString 'File.Substring(0, File.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    Return outcome
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of file names are you expecting? Are there any rules they will follow, like numbers always in front/back of filename? Do they have to be one after another, e.g. getting "34567" from "file_34567.txt"? Or are you just looking for numbers period, e.g. getting "34567" from "34_5file_nam6e7.txt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use a regular expression easily.

```
Dim numRegex As New Regex("\d+")
Dim number As String = numRegex.Match("Q:\2456_blah_blah\file.txt").Value
```

Comment: Regex is the way to go. Except I'd change it to `"^[A-Z]+\:\\.*\d+.*$"`

Comment: What does the Regex("\d+") do?  I'm just curious.

Comment: It's shorthand meaning one or digits in a row will be a matched. danyim's version is more specific to your example string and is better at matching exactly what you want.

Comment: Let's say I wanted to get the "blah_blah" string out of that same filename, can I use something similar to what you put?  I'm not familiar with regex.

Answer (score 0):

A lazy way would be to use Split:

```
TextBox2.Text = path.Split("\")(1).Split("_")(0)
```

Comment: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'  Is the error I get